# Why i can override protected field by public in scala?

Tags: scala

Code:

```scala
class Animal {
    protected val greeting: String = "Some noise"
}
    
class Cat extends Animal {
    override val greeting = "Meow"
}
new Cat().greeting // i have access to greeting. Why ?
new Animal().greeting // method greeting in class Animal cannot be accessed
```

Why i can override protected field by public ?

Comment: Why not? Liskov only says that a subtype has to provide everything its supertype provides, but it can do more. So, you can always widen the visibility restrictions on your subclasses but never make them more restrictive. A similar example is when in a subclass you override a method to accept a broader type or return a narrower one.

Comment: You can expand access in subclass, but you cannot restrict access because the restriction must be satisfied with base class requirement

Comment: You're right. Im tired)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In scala, instance fields (Members) are **public** by default.

thus, `override greeting` defined overridden `val greeting` as a public and not protected.
Use the protected access modifier to hide them from outside of the class as follows:

```
class Animal {
  protected val greeting: String = "Some noise"
}

 class Cat extends Animal {
  override protected val greeting = "Meow"
}
new Cat().greeting // // method greeting in class Cat cannot be accessed
new Animal().greeting // method greeting in class Animal cannot be accessed
```

Comment: I am pretty sure OPs question is why he / she can do that; since probably he / she expects that if the superclass declared it as protected then subclasses should respect that.

Comment: By definition of `protected` they are visible to the subclasses

Comment: I think you didn't understand me, sorry if I wasn't clear. - I believe _(note that I may be incorrect since it is just guessing)_ that OP believes that if you declared something protected in a superclass then the subclass has to declare it protected too, so he / she is surprised the compiler didn't fail _(or at least warned)_ and that the field is indeed public.

Comment: I still don't understand why to downvote this legit solution @HEX - I wanted to explain why it override it as `public` although you didn't explicitly mention it which i thought was the question in the first place

Comment: I do not think HEX was the one that down voted.

Comment: @ZviMints yes, it's wasn't me :-/